# Which PHP Package Can Count Word/PDF File Page Number

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

**At First:**

I use Laravel 5.1

**Want:**

User Can Upload PDF OR Word File,

Then The Application can **count page numbers** for user ,and show for it .

I don't Know Which Package Can Do it to Count Page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mPDF for Laravel](https://github.com/limweb/L5MPDF)

add this to a main mPDF class:

```
function getPageCount() {
   return count($this->pages);
}
```

and use something like this:

```
$PageCount = $this->getPageCount();
```

Comment: I read Source OF mPDF,and it'not a function to load PDF File,I think it only suitable for HTML To PDF,but i want read PDF Pages，form upload.